# Set fragment layout asynchronously

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` with some buttons that when pressed replace current fragment with another one. Now mots of that fragments require several seconds for set all views that contains, so I would like to show a `Spinner` while fragment views is under construction. 
I can't use `AsyncTask` for "build" `Fragment`, so i've try to run a thread inside `onCreateView` method of `Fragment` to show:

```
showLoadingDialog();
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setWidgets(view);
                    dismissLoadingDialog();
                }

            });
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

where `showLoadingDialog()` show a `Spinner` (and dismissLoadingDialog dismiss it), and setWidgets(view) it's the function that fill all views inside fragment.
This solution doesn't work because `Fragment` is showed only when setWidgets end, so no spinner is showed.

How can i do?

Comment: to have a delay use  a `Handler`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AsyncTask, and make your Fragment changes in the *onPostExecute()* method.

This method is designed to run back ON the UI thread and is specifically designed to be a place to handle UI operations after your Async (off the UI thread) operations are complete.

Comment: if i use asynctask for build UI  i obtain "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: You would have to share the code with the AsyncTask, I have no idea what you are doing without it.